# template implementations in multiple sources

Tags: c++, templates, header-files, code-cleanup, multiple-definition-error

I'm using the following pattern to keep template declarations and implementations separate:

---

### decl.h (declaration)

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  void DoIt();
}
```

---

### impl.cpp (implementation)

```
template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::DoIt() { // impl code 
};

template class Foo<int>;
template class Foo<float>;
```

---

Now i want to add a new method to Foo, but the impl.cpp file is already huge, so i want to move it to a separate file impl2.cpp;

---

### decl.h (declaration)

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  void DoIt();
  void RemoveIt();
}
```

---

### impl.cpp (implementation)

```
template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::DoIt() { // impl code 
};

template class Foo<int>;
template class Foo<float>;
```

---

### impl2.cpp (implementation)

```
template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::RemoveIt() { // impl code 
};

template class Foo<int>;
template class Foo<float>;
```

---

the main concern here are the duplicate instantiations, how do i avoid those?

Comment: Keep all the forced instantiations in impl.cpp and remove them from impl2.cpp? This is not something I have ever tried so I am not sure if that will work or if this is possible.

Comment: I wasnt aware that defining template methods in compile units is even possible o.O. As far as I know this shouldnt possible at all. From the template a real class/function is generated when the compilers encounters a concrete instantiation. Therefore splitting declaration and implementation is not allowed! Have you tried to use the template atleast once?

Comment: @Paranaix, sure, this is a well-known pattern

Comment: @lursche I actually dont believe you (no offense). As you can see in rhalbersma answere the only possibility would be using a #include in the header. In this case one cant call this a "implementation" or "compilation unit" though.

Comment: @Paranaix, look at the c++ faq: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follows:

1. Move definition of `Foo<T>::DoIt()` to some header file named
   ImplDoIt.h (not necessarily in the same directory as decl.h)
2. Same for `Foo<T>::RemoveIt()` - ImplRemoveIt.h
3. Include in your impl.cpp all these header files and instantiate the templates.

Comment: this is the right solution - a single impl.cpp is required to keep the instantiations - but the implementations can be keep organized in different ipp files

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the implementations for general template argument `T` into the header and the explicit instantiations for `int` and `float` in a source file.

```
// decl.h
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
  void DoIt();
  void RemoveIt();
}

#include "impl1.ipp"
#include "impl2.ipp"

// impl1.ipp
template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::DoIt() { // impl code 
};

// impl2.ipp
template <typename T>
void Foo<T>::RemoveIt() { // impl code 
};

// inst.cpp
#include "decl.h"
template class Foo<int>;   // explicit instantiation goes in source file
template class Foo<float>; // explicit instantiation goes in source file

// main.cpp
#include "decl.h"

int main()
{
    // call with concrete template arguments
    Foo<int>::DoIt();
    Foo<float>::RemoveIt();
}
```

Why? Because `DoIt` and `RemoveIt` are functions templates, not functions, and they cannot be compiled before seeing the template `T` being passed to them. So all clients of `Foo` need to include not only your header but also your implementation files. The most convenient way is to let the header include the implementations. That's why I renamed them to `.ipp`.

Comment: this is wrong; see this for more details http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/separate-template-fn-defn-from-decl.html the linker takes care of joining the template implementations to the client usages

Comment: @lurscher I think you should read the item just before the one you cite http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates-defn-vs-decl.html

Comment: @lurscher I updated my answer, does this solve your duplication question?

Comment: i've seen your edit. I take that you understand that there is nothing wrong with adding template implementations in .cpp as long as they have template instantiations right? if you try the examples on the FAQ or my question you'll see that it will work. The problem is, how, if possible, to split the implementation if further files (my guess is that is not possible)

Comment: @lurscher My answer gives a scalable solution. you simple add 1 source file per new member function of Foo, and there is no further duplication of instantiations. Why do you insist on putting everything into source files?

Comment: thanks, but it does not solve the underlying problem, and actually reverts the benefits of keeping implementations in other files (there will be multiple instantiations for each translation unit that includes the header) - PiotrNycz solution is the right one, i've commented in his answer why.

Comment: @lurscher my suggested file organization is identical to the one by PiotrNycz, except that I include the to .ipp files indirectly through decl.h

Comment: is not identical, he includes the ipp in the impl.cpp. So it means that i can include decl.h in a translation unit and it won't build any implementation.